# Unable to access property in base class

Tags: c#

I have the following base class:

```
namespace NamespaceA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public ClassA();

        public MyType Foo { get; }
    }
}
```

And the following class derived from it:

```
using NamespaceA;
namespace NamespaceB
{
    public sealed class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        ...
        private void MyFunc()
        {
            var foo = this.Foo;
        }
     }
 }
```

Everything compiles wonderfully.

When I run this, it crashes on accessing `this.Foo`. If I put a breakpoint inside the private method, before this line and use the Immediate Window to check `Foo`, I get the following:

> ```
> me: Foo
> Immediate Window: The name 'Foo' does not exist in the current context
> me: this.Foo
> Immediate Window: 'NamespaceB.ClassB' does not contain a definition for
> ```

`Foo` and no extension method `Foo` accepting a first argument of type `Namespace.ClassB` could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Any ideas what could be happening? Full disclosure, `ClassA` is a different assembly implemented by another group. If needed I can get to the code, but it is not readily available.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: That's anything but certainly not valid c++ code. Did you mean to tag something like [tag:c#] actually?

Comment: *"Class A is a different assembly implemented by another group."* Sounds like you need to get the code from them. Without their source code, you are basically coding blind.

Comment: "it crashes on accessing", how does it crash? Is it throwing an exception, if so, what is that exception?

Comment: Apologies. I am not sure why this appears tagged C++. This is my first time using the site and it appears to be correctly tagged as C#. It sounds like the problem is in the other assembly. I will attempt to get the debug assemblies from them. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to `ClassB`, but `Foo` is declared in `ClassA`. Try this:

```
public sealed class ClassB : ClassA
{
    ...
    private void MyFunc()
    {
        var foo = Foo; // or: var foo = base.Foo;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that yielded the same result. I suspect the problem in in the other assembly. I will head down that path.